# How do I add external executable to Go project

Tags: go

I am writing an application in Go. However on every platform my code will utilize external program compiled from another project in another language (e.g. C++ in Windows, Objective-C for Mac etc). This external executable is called with `os/exec` `exec.Command` function.

I can package my software with no problem, however one issue persists is that using `go run` will result in this file missing.

**Is there a way to tell `go` that it should include external file (and preferably also build it from source) whenever I do `$ go run myproj`?**

AFAIK, `go run` simply builds binary under a tmp directory, however it won't include any external files such as images etc. So for example when you have two files: `$GOPATH/src/main/main.go` and `$GOPATH/ext-tool.bin` and `main.go` content is:

```
package main

import "os/exec"

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("./ext-tool.bin")
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you shouldn't use `go run` for your project, use `go install` or `go build`  If you need a binary included you will need to provide that externally somehow, like any other dependency.

Comment: @JimB, I am aware how to build and package my application. The issue is I need to DEBUG with this binary included. All debuggers I can see are using `go run`, thus the question.

Comment: Oh, then just make sure the executable is in your PATH, or provide a full path the the executable. You shouldn't rely on a relative path in a binary.

Comment: @JimB that's what I am doing now. However this is a `coupled` software so debugging it with go app would be so much easier if I can just rebuild and include this external binary automagically on every debugger process restart.

Comment: You can do some trickery to get other things to be included with your source. You may go generate to be helpful, along with something like fileb0x, as mentioned below ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/54028731/151312 )

Answer (score 3):

One alternative would be to embed your executable in your application build.

This is done with [`go-bindata`](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) or its more recent successor [`unnoted/fileb0x`](https://github.com/unnoted/fileb0x).
There, you would have access to your embedded executable within an in-memory filesystem.

Comment: That could be an option. Though not for my case because that executable should be ran with different permissions (suid)

Comment: @AlexKey And this would not help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21706757/6309

Comment: Not unless I run it as root, then it makes no sense for my case as I could have embedded this functionality into main app from the start. And that would not solve more general case of having some resource files with the application (like images not converted into []bytes but as a plain files etc). It is rather rare to see application that has no resource files with it...

Comment: To elaborate on `suid`, the app is ran by user, but some actions shuold be perfromed with root privileges, so this `external binary` is a helper tool that has `suid` bit set to allow privilege escalation. That is a recommended and common way of implementing such cases. I have no problem distributing my app this way, but testability suffers a lot as I cannot use any debugger to test these functions as ALL debuggers I've seen use `go run` which means tmp directory and missing resource files

Comment: Also in the comments to the question it was mentioned to load those resources by absolute path, which would work for testing (and that's what I do now), but then packaging the app I have to change resources path to relative since I have no knowledge where user will install the application. And that also affects collaboration since other devs cannot just clone this project and start working, they have to first "setup environemnt" which means copying those files to hardcoded location matching with everyone else.

Comment: @AlexKey could you change the resource path relative to an environment variable? That way, the only environment setup required from other devs would be to set that unique environment variable.

Comment: @AlexKey Or: could you setup your path relative to the execution path of your executable? Then no setup required.

Comment: envvar - and then I need to instruct user to configure environment variable? relative path - then `go run` will have resources missing, that is exactly the issue. Go run executes build, but under tmp directory, and it only cares about `.go` files, which literally means there will be executable under /tmp.., but it won't copy resource files to the same location.

Comment: @AlexeyKamenskiy could you please share example/gist of getting handle to executable bundled inside go program and executing that as next step? All I see is read/write file which returns byte[]? I tried both go-bindata and unnoted/fileb0x. Thank you