# How do go modules work with installable commands?

Tags: go

I've recently started with Go 1.11 and love the modules. Apart from runtime dependencies I need to work with go modules during the build, e.g. during `go generate`.

How can I install a specific build dependency (e.g. github.com/aprice/embed/cmd/embed) and run that specific tool from which folder? Is `go get` the right tool for doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25922 proved helpful for me, especially

> when using build-only dependencies with modules the main point is version selection (not installing these!)
>
> To avoid installing you can modify your //go:generate directive to something like:
>
> ```
> //go:generate go run golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer ARGS
> ```

There is also the best practices repo: https://github.com/go-modules-by-example/index/blob/master/010_tools/README.md

Answer (score 8):

## If you get an error

I was not seeing the dependency that I wanted added to the go.mod and I was getting this error:

```
internal/tools/tools.go:6:5: import "github.com/UnnoTed/fileb0x" is a program, not an importable package
```

(fileb0x is the thing I'm trying to add)

I'm not 100% clear on the sequence of events that fixed it, but I did all of these things:

## Using a "tools" package

I made a `tools` directory:

```sh
mkdir -p internal/tools
```

I put the tools package inside of it (as mentioned above):

`internal/tools/tools.go`:

```golang
// +build tools

package tools

import (
    _ "github.com/UnnoTed/fileb0x"
)
```

Note that the tag is *mostly* not important. You could use foo:

```
// +build foo
```

However, you cannot use `ignore`. That's a special predefined tag.

```
// +build ignore

// NO NO NO NO NO
// `ignore` is a special keyword which (surprise) will cause
// the file to be ignore, even for dependencies
```

## Updating go.mod

The **best way** is probably to run `go mod tidy`:

```
go mod tidy
```

However, before I did that I ran a number of commands trying to figure out which one would cause it to go into `go.mod`:

```
go install github.com/UnnoTed/fileb0x # didn't seem to do the trick
go get
go generate ./...
go build ./...
go install ./...
go mod vendor
```

Later I did a `git reset` and `rm -rf ~/go/pkg/mod; mkdir ~/go/pkg/mod` and found that `go mod tidy` did well enough on its own.

## vendoring

In order to actually take advantage of the modules cache in a project you need to copy-in the source code

```
go mod vendor
```

That will grab all dependencies from go.mod

You also need to change nearly all of your go commands to use `-mod=vendor` in any `Makefile`s, `Dockerfile`s or other scripts.

```
go fmt -mod=vendor ./... # has a bug slated to be fixed in go1.15
go generate -mod=vendor ./...
go build -mod=vendor ./...
```

That includes `go build`, `go get`, `go install`, and any `go run` called by `go generate` (and even the `go generate` itself)

```
//go:generate go run -mod=vendor github.com/UnnoTed/fileb0x b0x.toml
package main

// ...
```

Comment: `go mod vendor` is the step that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

The convention is to add a file named "tools.go" that is guarded by a build constraint and imports all required tools:

```
// +build tools

package tools

import (
    _ "github.com/aprice/embed/cmd/embed"
)
```

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25922#issuecomment-412992431

The tools are then installed as usual in one of

- $GOBIN
- $GOPATH/bin
- $HOME/go/bin

You may also want to follow https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27653, which discusses future explicit support for tools.

Comment: Thanks for the related feature discussion

Comment: Actually, embed doesn't end up in any of theses paths though I've added the tools.go?

Comment: does this obsolete github.com/twitchtv/retool? or only for go 1.11?

Comment: @BruceAdams, this question and answer are about Go modules, which have been introduced in 1.11. vgo may work similar for earlier versions, but I never used that so I can't be sure. I'm also not familiar with retool, but judging from the readme the approach outlined here does render it obsolete.

Comment: Retool is a good solution for older versions of go. The modules solution is better for go 1.11 and later though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086136/fixing-versions-of-tools-used-by-go/53089261#53089261

Comment: I tried that, but I get "tools/tools.go:6:5: import "github.com/UnnoTed/fileb0x" is a program, not an importable package". Other suggestions?

Comment: @CoolAJ86, sounds like you forgot the build constraint.

Answer (score 2):

`tools.go` is a great solution if you're building an app or service. But if you're building a library, `tools.go` still leaks dependencies to things consuming your library (your tools are still there as `indirect` dependencies, and `go mod tidy` will pull them in since it considers *every possible target*). That's not the end of the world since those modules never end up in the actual built binaries of the consumer, but it's still messy.

https://github.com/myitcv/gobin/issues/44 is probably the most promising approach to fixing this long term, but short term I've used a combination of the "internal module" approach explained there along with https://github.com/izumin5210/gex.

First, I install `gex` globally:

```
GO111MODULE=off go get github.com/izumin5210/gex/cmd/gex
```

Then *before actually using gex* I create a structure like this:

```
myproject/
\
  - go.mod: module github.com/ysamlan/myproject
  \
    internal/
    \
      tools/
       - go.mod: module github.com/ysamlan/myproject/tools
```

To install a build-only tool I just `cd internal/tools` and run `gex --add (sometool)`, which puts that tool in `internal/tools/bin`. CI scripts and other folks that want to build my stuff locally just need to run `cd internal/tools && gex --build` to reliably and reproducibly populate the tool binaries, but the top-level go.mod is unchanged.

The key piece there is creating that `internal/tools/go.mod` file with a *different* module path than the one the root project uses, and then only running `gex` from that directory.