# fixing versions of tools used by go

Tags: go, glide-golang

I am looking to create reproducible builds with go. 
For individual projects we are using glide.

So for example I use:

```
glide get github.com/stretchr/testify
```

to fix the version of the "testify" package.
This does not work for tools however.
For example:

```
glide install github.com/tebeka/go2xunit
```

returns success but does not actually install go2xunit
so I have to use:

```
go get github.com/tebeka/go2xunit
```

which installs *go2xunit* to *$GOPATH/bin*.

**Q How can I fix the version of tools like go2xunit?**

I also note that [glide says use dep instead](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) and dep says [golang has diverged from its implementation](https://github.com/golang/dep) and will probably end up using something based on [vgo](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/vgo). There are a plethora of dependency management tools for go perhaps one of the less well known ones supports this?

In case its relevant I'm using go 1.7.4 as provided by Debian9.

Comment: I'm not sure about other go dependency tools, but dep will also not install binaries. There's an [issue](https://github.com/golang/dep/issues/221) about it already open. What I do, is keep a separate gotools GOPATH where I keep all my go based tools. Especially ones that vscode uses. This keeps my project GOPATH from being "contaminated" with external things.

Comment: Its not clear if vgo will solve this either - https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/24301-versioned-go.md

Comment: I just played around with the `go mod` that was added in go1.11. It like the other dependency tools don't install packages, they just download them. So you won't be able to track a build dependency tool like go2xunit.

Comment: Doh! Reproducible builds are still a way off then!
Thanks for the insight though.

Comment: I'm sure this must be a known issue but having failed to find it I've raised it here - https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28512

Comment: For go mod see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428230/how-do-go-modules-work-with-installable-commands/52430466#52430466

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for go1.11 using go modules is to create a [fake tools package](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25922).
You create a *tools.go* file like the following:

```
// +build tools

package tools

import (
        _ "github.com/tebeka/go2xunit"
)
```

*+build* tools is a magic comment which prevents the package being built.

```
>go mod init tools
```

Will create a *go.mod* file for the fake *tools* package

```
>go install github.com/tebeka/go2xunit
```

Will install go2xunit and update go.mod as follows.

```
module tools

require github.com/tebeka/go2xunit v1.4.8 // indirect
```

Now if you run *go install github.com/tebeka/go2xunit* in the future (for a clean build say) its version will be fixed to v1.4 by the go.mod

---

For versions of go before 1.11 the tool to use is [retool](https://github.com/twitchtv/retool).
It works like this:

bootstrap:

```
go get github.com/twitchtv/retool
```

add tool:

```
retool add github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/go-bindata origin/master
```

use tool:

```
retool do go-bindata -pkg testdata -o ./testdata/testdata.go ./testdata/data.json
```

Adding support for this may be on the roadmap to target go 1.12 (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27653)

Comment: Note that this answer is essentially a duplicate of the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428230/how-do-go-modules-work-with-installable-commands?noredirect=1&lq=1 except that this also covers older versions of go

Answer (score 0):

I did this very similarly, but just different enough that I think it's worth sharing again:

## If you get an error

I was not seeing the dependency that I wanted added to the go.mod and I was getting this error:

```
tools/tools.go:6:5: import "github.com/UnnoTed/fileb0x" is a program, not an importable package
```

(fileb0x is the thing I'm trying to add)

I'm not 100% clear on the sequence of events that fixed it, but I did all of these things:

## Using a "tools" package

I made a `tools` directory:

```
mkdir -p tools
```

I put the tools package inside of it (as mentioned above):

```
// +build tools

package tools

import (
    _ "github.com/UnnoTed/fileb0x"
)
```

Note that the tag is *mostly* not important. You could use foo:

```
// +build foo
```

However, you cannot use `ignore`. That's a special predefined tag.

```
// +build ignore

// NO NO NO NO NO
// `ignore` is a special keyword which (surprise) will cause
// the file to be ignore, even for dependencies
```

## Updating go.mod

The **best way** is probably to run `go mod tidy`:

```
go mod tidy
```

However, before I did that I ran a number of commands trying to figure out which one would cause it to go into `go.mod`:

```
go install github.com/UnnoTed/fileb0x # didn't seem to do the trick
go get
go generate ./...
go build ./...
go install ./...
go mod vendor
```

Later I did a `git reset` and `rm -rf ~/go/pkg/mod; mkdir ~/go/pkg/mod` and found that `go mod tidy` did well enough on its own.

## vendoring

In order to actually take advantage of the modules cache in a project you need to copy-in the source code

```
go mod vendor
```

That will grab all dependencies from go.mod

You also need to change nearly all of your go commands to use `-mod=vendor` in any `Makefile`s, `Dockerfile`s or other scripts.

```
go fmt -mod=vendor ./... # has a bug which should be fixed in go1.15
go generate -mod=vendor ./...
go build -mod=vendor ./...
```

That includes `go build`, `go get`, `go install`, and any `go run` called by `go generate` (and even the `go generate` itself)

```
//go:generate go run -mod=vendor github.com/UnnoTed/fileb0x b0x.toml
package main

// ...
```