# How to exec shell command as normal user while current user is root

Tags: go

I run `go run main.go` as root, but I want to execute `top` in main.go as a normal user.

```
# main.go
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func run() {
    cmd := exec.CommandContext(context.TODO(), "bash", "-c", "top")
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(
            cmd.ProcessState.Success())
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(
        cmd.ProcessState.Success())
}

func main() {
    run()
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Note: Never use `go run main.go`. Go code is managed by package, not file. Use `go run .` instead, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    out, err := exec.Command("sudo", "-u", "YOURUSERNAME", "top", "-n", "1", "-b").Output()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: thx, but i don't want to use sudo, su, runuser. so these is other answers?

Comment: i got https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705950/running-external-commands-through-os-exec-under-another-user

Answer (score 0):

try execute command like this:

```
su fakeuser -c 'top -u `whoami`'
```

Comment: thx, but i don't want to use sudo, su, runuser. so these is other answers?

Comment: i got https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705950/running-external-commands-through-os-exec-under-another-user